# PHP AJAX - How to show popup notification after form submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Just in case!
Possible duplicates:

[PHP-Jquery-AJAX, show popup message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26603704/php-jquery-ajax-show-popup-message)
[Form submission PHP ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569407/form-submission-php-ajax)
[Form submission PHP ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569407/form-submission-php-ajax)
[Show a success message after PHP form submission using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38973913/show-a-success-message-after-php-form-submission-using-ajax)
[jquery popup after form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24741365/jquery-popup-after-form-submission)
[How to show a success message after PHP form submission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31628948/how-to-show-a-success-message-after-php-form-submission)
[PHP Ajax Form Submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37898151/php-ajax-form-submission)

I am trying to show a "notification popup box" after successful form submission to DB.

I tested it with `alert();` and its working fine, but the issue is the auto redirect.

**HTML form:**

```
<form action="form-process" id="reportsForm" method="POST"></form>
```

**routes.php:**

```
//Reports pages
get('/all-reports', '/pages/reports/all-reports.php');
get('/add-new-report', '/pages/reports/add-new-report.php');

//Reports form subbmision
post('/form-process', '/backend/form-process.php');
```

**Ajax:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#reportsForm").submit(function() {
        var cccEmployee = $("#ccc_employee").val();
        var irNumber = $("#IR_number").val();
        var caseType = $("#case_type").val();
        var caseLocation = $("#caseLocation").val();
        var startDateTime = $("#startDate").val();
        var endDateTime = $("#endDate").val();
        var caseDesc = $("#case_description").val();
        var actionsTaken = $("#action_taken").val();
        var caseDetails = $("#details").val();
        var caseNotes = $("#notes").val();
        var caseRecommendation = $("#recommendation").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./backend/form-process.php",
            success: function() {
                alert("sucess");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I tried to redirect using `window.location` & `headers()` then the code fails.
I am using PHP [routing library](https://phprouter.com/) and because of it somehow it's ruining my Ajax request?

Comment: **the issue is the auto redirect** Do you mean (1) you cannot show the popup after ajax return ? or (2) you want to get redirected after popup display but failed ?

Comment: @KenLee when "submit" is clicked, it shows the alert THEN redirects to white page after clicking "OK". I want to show the alert and stay in the form page.

Answer (score 2):

Try stop default handle of form ( use attribute action as process URL ) with **preventDefault**

```
$("#reportsForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // add this
    var cccEmployee = $("#ccc_employee").val();
    ....
```

Comment: OK it's not redirecting and showing the alert, good. But the data is not saved to DB...

Comment: I saw you just sent post request to URL without data. Append it and tell me about result.

Comment: @Mòe u need to send data to the php file do some survey on how to send data in ajax, `data: this.serialize(),` something like this.

Comment: I kept trying to use "data:" in every way I found in my search...doesn't work yet..

Comment: Yeah I give up...I tried everything I could...here is where I stopped: https://imgur.com/IHRBtvh

Comment: Be patient, my friend. You almost get result. Just find a way to debug. First, did you send a right format, right url, and correct variable ?, use chrome debug ( or other browsers) to detect . On server, just var_dump all posted variable, check it, process and return result. Debug step by step. ( Some change maybe have effect : type of ajax must be uppercase, set contentType to json ...). Good luck